# Algorithm for scheduling jobs based on relative priority

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a number of jobs `(J1, J2, ...)` and there priority `(P1, P2, ...)` and based on there relative priority.
I have to schedule them in `minimum number of steps`.

Example for `5 jobs with 4 rules` of relative priority:

P(J1) > P(J3)

P(J2) > P(J3)

P(J3) > P(J4)

P(J2) > P(J5)

Solution: `P1, P2, P3, P4, P5` OR `P1, P2, P3, P5, P4`

There maybe more than one solution but the solution should confirm to above 4 rules.

Comment: there are plenty of priority queues base on heap-algorithms. you can look/use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [topological sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Here you have a directed graph where the vertices are the jobs and there is an edge from `A` to `B` iff `P(A) > P(B)`.